# Gson Format Output Json

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a java object with `id,text,body,title` as class members with appropriate getters and setters and use Gson to convert POJO to json

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(object);
```

This returns a follwoing josn String

```
   {
      "id" : 1,
      "text" : "Some text",
      "body" : "Some text.",
      "title" : "Some title."
    }
```

How do i get the above json wrapped as following

```
"i1":{
  "i2":{
      "id" : 1,
      "text" : "Some text",
      "body" : "Some text.",
      "title" : "Some title."
     } 
  }
}
```

Right now the `toString()` method is just empty. Should that be modified or should i1 and i2 be class members too?

Comment: One very fast way would be to "\"i1\":{ \"i2\":"+json+"}}".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap object with JsonObjects before turning into a json string. Something like this:

```
JsonObject i1 = new JsonObject();
JsonObject i0 = new JsonObject();
i1.add("i2", gson.toJsonTree(object));
i0.add("i1", i1);
String results = gson.toJson(i0);
System.out.println("results=" + results);
```